# Combobox in DataGrid which is empty at first (Content loads from Database)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datagrid

I've a question. I have a tab with a empty datagrid. When the program starts, the datagrid gets filled with data from a database. You can edit it and afterwards save it by pressing the button called 'Opslaan' (Dutch for save). The problem is, on the tab 'Bestellingen' there is 1 field called State, with the states being 'Delivered', 'Sent', 'Processing'. So I would like this specific field to be like a combobox, since now the user has to type in one of the states, and if the user makes a typing error he get's an error, with a combobox the user experience would be enhanced. Could someone explain to me how and if I'm able to do this?

```
<Window x:Class="SFES.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SFES"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Super Fontys Entertainment System" Height="396.563" Width="711.25" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
    <TabControl x:Name="tabControl" Margin="0,0,0.4,-0.2">
        <TabItem Header="Klanten">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <DataGrid x:Name="KlantenDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding }" Margin="0,19,0.4,0.4"/>
                <Button x:Name="KlantenOpslaan" Content="Opslaan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="KlantenOpslaan_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Bestellingen">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <DataGrid x:Name="BestellingenDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding }" Margin="0,19,0.4,0.4"/>
                <Button x:Name="OpslaanBestellingen" Content="Opslaan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="OpslaanBestellingen_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Spelers">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <DataGrid x:Name="SpelersDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding }" Margin="0,19,0.4,0.4"/>
                <Button x:Name="SpelersOpslaan" Content="Opslaan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="SpelersOpslaan_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Leveranciers">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <DataGrid x:Name="LeveranciersDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding }" Margin="0,19,0.4,0.4"/>
                <Button x:Name="LeveranciersOpslaan" Content="Opslaan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="LeveranciersOpslaan_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Highscores">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <DataGrid x:Name="HighscoresDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding }" Margin="0,19,0.4,0.4"/>
                <Button x:Name="HighscoresOpslaan" Content="Opslaan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="HighscoresOpslaan_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Spellen">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <DataGrid x:Name="SpellenDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding }" Margin="0,19,0.4,0.4"/>
                <Button x:Name="OpslaanSpellen" Content="Opslaan" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.504,0.541" Click="OpslaanSpellen_Click"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

```
public DataTable VulTabellen(string Commando)
    {
        MyConnection.Open();
        MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand(Commando, MyConnection);
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter Reader = new MySqlDataAdapter(Command);
        Reader.Fill(DT);
        MyConnection.Close();
        return DT;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30666133/4664754

Answer (score 0):

In you XAML, you need to declare a combobox type column like this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="State" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding States}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding States}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Then you need to set the `DataContext` to something other than `DataTable`. Like this:

```
public class GridData
{
    public DataTable Table { get; set; }

    // for the combobox see the property name. This is also in XAML above
    public List<string> States {get; set; } 
}
```

When you have read the data from datareader, you need to create the above class.